# Gradle Task from Plugin Doesn't Run on "Build", But Does Run on "Clean"

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

We have an Android project which requires a certain Gradle Plugin Task to run before we build the APK. (The plugin is written by us)

**We want to run the task automatically before every build**.

If we use the deprecated `task.execute()` then we get a warning that it will be unavailable starting with version 5.0 or something like that.

If we use the `dependsOn` as recommended, then `testTask1` is not before BUILD, but only after CLEAN. (all explained in the comments below)

I've been over the gradle docs, and many other SO threads, but I have yet to find a solution.

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {

    repositories {
        flatDir { dirs 'libs' }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3"

        // our platform-tools plugin, in charge of some gradle tasks
        classpath 'sofakingforevre:test-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    }
}


apply plugin: 'test-plugin'


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}


// OPTION 1 - USING EXECUTE()

// this task works as expected when calling "clean", but also when calling "assemble".
// the problem here is that the "execute" method has been deprecated, and we want to prepare for Gradle 5.0

// CLEAN - testTask1 is called :)
// BUILD - testTask1 is called :)
// DEPRECATION WARNING :(
task buildPlatformExecute {

    println("executing")

    // this task is created by the plugin
    tasks.getByName("testTask1").execute()


}

clean.dependsOn buildPlatformExecute

// OPTION 2 - USING DEPENDSON()

// this tasks works as expected when calling "clean", but DOES NOT WORK when calling "assemble".
// If we call we call assemble, the "executing" text does print, but "testTask1" would not run.

// CLEAN - testTask1 is called :)
// BUILD - testTask1 is NOT CALLED :(
task buildPlatformDependency {

    println("executing")

    // this task is created by the plugin
    dependsOn 'testTask1'
}

clean.dependsOn buildPlatformDependency
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issues with your *OPTION 1* solution**

- you are using deprecated `task.execute()` API (you are already aware of that)
- you are mixing *configuration* and *execution* phases (a common Gradle mistake...):

Since you did not wrap `tasks.getByName("testTask1").execute()` in a `doLast {}` of `doFirst {}` block in `buildPlatformExecute` task : the `testTask1` task will always be executed, whatever task you will invoke. You do not even need to create dependency between `clean` task and your custom task ( e.g.: try to execute simple "help" task with`./gradlew help` you will see that `testTask1` is also executed: this is certainly not what you want)

More information here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html

**Issue with your *OPTION2* solution**

You created a dependency between `clean` task and`buildPlatformDependency` task :

- when executing `clean` tasks, `testTask1` task will be executed as expected, but
- there is no dependency between `build` (or `assemble`) task and `clean` task: that's why when you execute `build` task, `clean` task is not executed (so `testTask1` won't be triggered)

**Solution**

The best approach would be to hook you custom task `testTask1` in the correct place in your project build lifecycle, using `Task.dependsOn` API. The "correct" place depends on what your task is responsible for in the build process: for example if your task needs to be executed BEFORE `assemble` task, simply create dependency  `assemble.dependsOn testTask1`

Comment: Due to the confusion of *configuration phase* and *execution phase* the output of the `println` statements is not triggered during execution, too. It will print on any Gradle invocation.

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of the answer, but you saved me :)